# Supervisor using date to name the logfile

Tags: supervisord

I am using the supervisor and I want to make the logfile by day.

The actual script :

```
stdout_logfile=/var/www/worker.log
```

I tried something like

```
stdout_logfile=/var/www/%(date)s.log
stdout_logfile=/var/www/(date '+%Y-%m-%d').log
```

and it didn't work, what can I do to make the output by day ?
Thanks,